# PyQt Prevent QInputDialog from closing on ESC/Enter cross click

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qinputdialog

I created QInputDialog and configured event filter in it, but I don't know how to prevent it from closing on ESC or ENTER button click in `eventFilter(self, widget, event)` method.

```
 self.inDialog = QInputDialog(self)
 #some config...
 self.inDialog.setLabelText('')
 self.nameAction.setText('&Nazwa pola głównego ✔')
 self.inDialog.show()
```

My event filter concept:

```
def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
    if isinstance(event, QtGui.QKeyEvent):
        if event.key() == 16777220:
            return False
    # here I want to call super somehow?
    return
```

It is worth mentioning that I am doing all this operations in QMainWindow class from which I am calling this QInputdialog. I would prefer not to subclass QDialog and write everything manually.

Comment: My mistake - it is QInputDialog.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: what is `Red` in `ESC/Enter/Red`?

Comment: edited - buttons on keyboard.

Comment: try with my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid that the event happens to the `QInputDialog` you must return `True` in the filter, on the other hand it is better to use the [`Qt::Key`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum) to make a more readable code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")
        button.clicked.connect(self.opendialog)
        self.setCentralWidget(button)

        self.inDialog = QtWidgets.QInputDialog()
        self.inDialog.setLabelText('')
        self.inDialog.installEventFilter(self)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def opendialog(self):
        if self.inDialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            print("Acepted")
            print(self.inDialog.textValue())

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.inDialog and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, 
                QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape, 
                QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter,):
                return True
        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**  + Disable close button:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if obj is self.inDialog:
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Return, 
                QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape, 
                QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter,):
                return True
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Close:
            event.ignore()
            return True
    return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Comment: Do you know how to disable 'close' button in window? (red cross in the right upper corner)

Comment: Worked! Thanks!